# How to ignore pages in Middleman Sitemap

Tags: ruby, sitemap, middleman

I'm new to Middleman (and Ruby) and am working on an HTML and XML sitemap. I've got the sitemap generated correctly using this [method](https://gist.github.com/lukebowerman/3287848).

```
<% pages = sitemap.resources.find_all{|p| p.source_file.match(/\.html/) } %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <% pages.each do |p| %>
  <url>
  <loc>http://youdomain.com/<%=p.destination_path.gsub('/index.html','')%></loc>
  <priority>0.7</priority> 
</url>
<% end %>
</urlset>
```

But this is all `.html` pages within the site. How do I exclude certain pages (gated content, AB test pages, etc) from the query so they are not included in the sitemap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add more criteria to your `.find_all` block:

```rb
.find_all { |p|
  p.source_file.match(/\.html/)
  && p.whatever !== 'something'
}
```

Comment: So, I'm guessing I could set `'something'` to be a condition I've set in the frontmatter of the pages I don't want included? A `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, frontmatter is the ideal place for that.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up figuring out it was easier for me to remove  whole directories as well as individual files.

`<% pages = sitemap.resources.find_all{|p| p.source_file.match(/\.html/) && !p.data.nomap == true && !p.path.match(/misc/) && !p.path.match(/view/) } %>`